# assign a specific color to the overlapping area between two circles

Tags: matlab, plot, overlap

I'm using this code to draw two circles.It randomly colors the areas in the final image. But I want to assign specific shades of grey for the circles and a different shade for the overlapping area.

```
% size of image
sz = [800 800];

% generate coordinates
y = 1:sz(1);
x = 1:sz(2);
[xx, yy] = meshgrid(x, y);
% draw circles
ci1 = (xx-300).^2 + (yy-400).^2 <= 200^2;
ci2 = (xx-500).^2 + (yy-400).^2 <= 200^2;

% draw image containing circles
imagesc (ci1 + ci2 );
colormap(gray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use binary encoding of the different areas, together with a custom colormap:

```
% draw image containing circles
imagesc (ci1 + 2 * ci2 );
caxis([-0.5, 3.5])
colormap([0 0 0         % background: black
          1 0 0         % circle 1: red
          0 1 0         % circle 2: green
          0 0 1])       % overlap: blue
```

The plotted data contain 0 for the background, 1 for circle 1, 2 for circle 2, and 3 for the overlap. The `caxis` and the `colormap` commands map the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3 to the colors black, red, green, blue specified as RGB-triplets. Adjust the entries in the colormap to get the specific shades of gray you'd like.

NB: Your code lacks a line `[xx, yy] = meshgrid(x, y);`